# Spring @Configuration @Bean - How can I get more context information for bean creation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration

I'd like to create a bean based on "which instance of which class the field belongs to (or even, just to which class this field belongs to). Something like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    SomeClass getTheRightInstance(SomeContext someContext) {
        if(someContext.getinjectedFieldHostInstance.getId() == 7) {
            return new SpecificSomeClassImplForId7();
        } else {
            return new SomeClass();
        }
    }
```

Bean is to be injected into following `field`:

```
public class A {
   private int final id;
   @Inject private SomeClass field;
   int getId();
   public A() {
     id = SerialIdGenerator.getNextID();
   }
}
```

Select bean injected into `A`'s `field` based on `A` instance's `id`

```
public staitc void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A();  // has id '1', gets field injected with SimpleClass 
    A a2 = new A();  // has id '2', gets field injected with SimpleClass
    ...
    A a7 = new A();  // gets field injected with SpecificSomeClassImplForId7
    ...
    A last= new A();  // has id!=7, gets field injected with SimpleClass

}
```

The general idea is to have the decision as to which implementation to inject to which field in which class be defined in code.

Can I inject different bean instances to the same field of different instances of the same class? How can you configure it through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bean you define is a Singleton, so its created at Context-Initialization before the app know that anyone might autowire the value. You must create the Bean as `Prototype` to request the instance on autowire only.

This is still not possible to get infos about the autowire-target. You can use `*Aware`-interfaces to get

- very own unique Beanname
- Beanfactory
- ApplicationContext

But neither the `target` of the autowire nor the `class` of the target.

Notice that: if the autowire-field has been marked as `@Lazy` and the Bean's scope is `Prototype` you can elaborate the exact time the bean autowires using the bean's `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do that but it seems like a bad idea.

Classes should never configure their behaviour around their caller, it leads to code that is tightly coupled and not very portable.

Instead, you should find out what makes those 2 fields different and refactor them to use 2 different interfaces (which may even have a common super interface in case of shared functionality). Then you can easily provide 2 different implementations for those interfaces. In your case you could also write a class that handles the specific case for id == 7 and the other cases (maybe via delegation) and use another way of configuring the instance either after or while injecting it into A.

I'm not aware of any possibility to do what you want directly.

Edit: After discussing a bit further in the comments and understanding more what you want to accomplish I think having one factory to create A instances would be best:

```
@Service
class AFactory {

    @Autowired
    private SpecificSomeClassImplForId7 specificSomeClassImplForId7;

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClass;

    public A makeA() {
        if(isSpecialA()) {
            return new A(specificSomeClassImplForId7);
        } else {
            return new A(someClass);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this factory in other Spring Beans in your Application to make As.

Comment: Thank you. What I'm trying to do (and maybe DI is not the right approach) is to build a tree of instances based on interfaces and different implementations. Instances of class `A` need to have a `SomeClass` child, but not always the same instance and not always the same implementation.

Comment: A good example is class Car which has four wheels, each having a tier. Front wheels have `Miche` type tires with 30 PSI. Rear wheels have wide `GoodY` tires with 28 PSI. I want to read this configuration from a file, and have different cars configured with different sets of tires and each wheel be configure differently based on the car it is in, and whether it is front or rear wheel of that car instance.

Comment: I see. In that case you might want to have the As have access to the Application Context directly and search for the right implementations themselves. You can just autowire the ApplicationContext class and then have A pick the right tires. The tires shouldn't concern themselves with the car they're on though.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe. Indeed the tires should not know which car they belong to. I want the mechanic (the @Configuration class) that needs to provide tires for a car to be smarter. So it checks which type car it is, and check if it is a tier for the front or rear wheels, and check if there is a special request from the customer buying that specific car instance. Then, the mechanic can build the right tier, or grab one off the shelf, and provide it for that specific car, for that specific wheel.

Comment: I get what you're saying. Maybe injecting dependencies into the car is indeed not the right approach then. Instead you could write a Factory class that will get all the different tyre implementations injected and then it can decide how to build cars, instead of letting Spring build them.